# Why does the Iterator::filter method accept a mutable reference as self?

Tags: rust, self

The signature of `Iterator::filter` is

```
fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P>
where
    Self: Sized,
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

Because it has `self` as the first parameter, I was assuming I would have to pass the iterator by value, thus moving ownership to that function. However,
I am able to call it with just a ref mut and the code compiles and runs. For example:

```
fn char_count(i: &mut impl Iterator<Item=char>, c: char) -> usize {
    i.filter(|&x| c == x).count()
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: at some point, every rustacean understand that `self` can be a reference, and then a new world open to them, full of flower and happiness.

Comment: I think I see where you are getting. Care to elaborate or direct me to some reference?

Comment: `Iterator` is implemented for every [`&'_ mut Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13) so if the original Iterator is Sized, filter is implemented, and so filter is implement on `&mut Iterator` so `self` is `&mut Iterator`. Magic !

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I now get the main idea.

Comment: @Stargateur Write that in an answer!

Answer (score -1):

There is confusion about the two parameters here.

The `self` parameter refers to the original iterator. That is, `filter()` moves whatever the original iterator is into the new `Filter` struct, which takes ownership of that iterator (the `Self` in `Filter<Self, _>`)

The `predicate` is a `FnMut` because it does not need to be an `Fn`. That is, the function provided as `predicate` is allowed to modify the context it captures while it executes. This is possible because `Filter` itself does not borrow `predicate` when it calls it. If it did, `predicate` would have to be an `Fn(&Self::Item)`.

The `predicate` takes the iterator's items by reference. Notice the sigil in the signature `FnMut(&Self::Item)`.

Comment: "filter() moves whatever the original iterator is into the new Filter struct, which takes ownership of that iterator" My question hits this point exactly. How can you move the "original iterator" to the new filter struct if in the char_count function you only have a reference to it?

Comment: Move the reference. A `&mut T` is just another type `U`. And there is an [impl in the stdlib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13) for any `&mut T` where `T` is `Iterator` to also implement `Iterator`.

Comment: Now I see! Thank you for the clarification